# Error with GMP with C++ in Netbeans (Windows 64-Bit)

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, cygwin, gmp

I'm doing a project for school in which I am doing all kinds of different calculations involving prime numbers. These numbers tend to go quite big, hence I went looking for an arbitrary precision library. I decided to go for GMP since I had used it earlier in Game Maker (a relatively unknown program) since someone had made a dll for it.

Now, I have followed the install manual and went ahead to compile GMP. I had great difficulty in doing this as I am totally unfamiliar with UNIX and cygwin. Now that I have tried to include gmpxx.h in Netbeans for a test program, things are going wrong. My code is as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mpz_t a;
    mpz_init(a);
    //cout << mpz_probab_prime_p(a,20);
    mpz_clear(a);
}
```

For both mpz_init and mpz_clear I am getting the same error:

> relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol '__gmpz_[init/clear]'

I am just guessing, but the problem could be any of the following:

- Wrongly compiled
- Bad code
- Improper includes/links

It could very well be the latter, although I have experimented with adding directories for the header files and such. How would I fix this error?

*Thanks in advance!*

**Edit:**
Since this is my first post, could you point out what I need to clarify in order to make this question answerable?

**Edit2:**
This is the compiling log in Netbeans:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/firsttestgmp.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++ -Lpath/to/gmp/lib -lgmpxx -lgmp    -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/firsttestgmp build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP/main.cpp:22:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__gmpz_init'
/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP/main.cpp:24:(.text+0x21): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__gmpz_clear'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/firsttestgmp.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/firsttestgmp.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

**Edit3:**
As @rubenvd pointed out, the real error is this:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/e/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FirstTestGMP/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
```

Comment: You should include the compilation command and the complete error you get. That will make it a lot easier for us to discover what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @rubenvb I'm very sorry I didn't see your comment. My compilation line is now the following: `-Lpath/to/gmp/lib -lgmpxx -lgmp -g` I think you could see that in the log too, though.

Comment: your real error is `undefined reference to '__gmpz_init'`. That's why you need to always show the _full_ error ;-).

Comment: I have changed it in they main post, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I fixed my problem by going to:
Properties > Build > Linker > Libraries > Add Library
Then adding gmp.a and gmpxx.a, which I found in the gmp directory that I compiled.

Answer (score 0):

It's important that linked libraries come *after* the object files which contain references to them. So Your compile command will need to be:

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/firsttestgmp build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

If you installed GMP in a nonstandard location (which doesn't seem to be the case), you'll need to add the path to the library directory using the `-L` option.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I did have `-lgmpxx -lgmp` but not the Lpath so I added that. It's still not working compiling , though. I will hereby include the compiler log, in case that helps. It is in the main question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jello The `-Lpath/to/gmp/lib` was only a placeholder. In reality it might be something like `-L/opt/gmp/lib`. But as you're using Cygwin you most likely don't need it anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make it refer to the right directory and see whether this gives better results.

Comment: Unfortunately, it hasn't changed anything. I also tested adding the -I flag, which had the same result.

Comment: `nm -D /path/to/gmp/lib/libgmp.so|grep mpz_init` (or `libgmp.a` without `-D`) check if you are getting `__gmpz_init` (double-check the number of leading `_`).

Comment: @Jelle did you place the `-lgmpxx -lgmp` at the end of your command?

Comment: There is no directory lib and there is no file libgmp.so. Neither is there a file libgmp.a. I'm pretty sure it is not. If it has to be at the end, may I ask you how to do that? Thanks for the answers!

Comment: In my last comment I was referring to what @rubenvb said, namely: "did you place the -lgmpxx -lgmp at the end of your command?"

Comment: @rubenvb What does my compilation line have to look like and how do I change it in Netbeans? Could you give an example please?